# 'Cursor not found' error when use a Tailable Cursor with NoCursorTimeout

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I created a capped collection with a 50M default size. More recently, I noticed that I get a `Cursor not found` error when a capped collection storage size goes over 50M. I'm not sure what reason causes this: I never get this error before when a capped collection size went less than a default maximum size.

```js
if (this._cursor == null || this._cursor.IsDead)
{                 
   var cursor = this._queueCollection.Find(Query.GT("_id", this._lastId))
            .SetFlags(QueryFlags.AwaitData |
            QueryFlags.TailableCursor |
            QueryFlags.NoCursorTimeout)
            .SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending("$natural")); 
    this._cursor =(MongoCursorEnumerator<QueueMessage<T>>)cursor.GetEnumerator();
}

try
{
    if (this._cursor.MoveNext())
        //do some things
        return this._cursor.Current;
    else
     {
         if (this._cursor.IsDead){
               this._cursor.Dispose();
               this._cursor=null;
         }
     }
     return null;
}
catch{}
```

The **this._cursor.MoveNext()** will throw a `cursor not found` exception (occasionally, not always thrown. Is my code wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found what cause this error.

Tailable cursors may become dead, or invalid, if either:

1. The query returns no match.
2. *The cursor returns the document at the “end” of the collection and then the application deletes those document.*

reference from a mongodb official website about create tailable cursor (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/)

In my application, when a `cursor not found' exception is thrown it always is because the cursor returns the document at the “end” of the collection and then the application deletes those document.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `foreach`:

```
var query1 = new QueryBuilder<Message>().GT(m => m.date, lastTransferredMessageDate);
var result = messagesCollection.FindAs<Message>(query1).SetFlags(QueryFlags.NoCursorTimeout);

foreach (var message in result)
{
  // Your code
}
```